# Given a Python string describing object.attribute, how do I separate the attributes's namespace from the attribute?

Tags: python, namespaces, getattr, setattr

Given a Python string describing object.attribute, how do I separate the attributes's namespace from the attribute?

Desired Examples:

```
ns_attr_split("obj.attr") => ("obj", "attr")
ns_attr_split("obj.arr[0]") => ("obj", "arr[0]")
ns_attr_split("obj.dict['key']") => ("obj", "dict['key']")
ns_attr_split("mod.obj.attr") => ("mod.obj", "attr")
ns_attr_split("obj.dict['key.word']") => ("obj", "dict['key.word']")
```

Note: I understand writing my own string parser would be one option, but I am looking for a more elegant solution to this. Rolling my own string parser isn't as simple as an rsplit on '.' because of the last option listed above where a given keyword may contain the namespace delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently discovered the tokenize library for tokenizing python source code. Using this library I've come up with this little code snippet:

```
import tokenize
import StringIO

def ns_attr_split(s):
  arr = []
  last_delim = -1
  cnt = 0

  # Tokenize the expression, tracking the last namespace
  # delimiter index in last_delim
  str_io = StringIO.StringIO(s)
  for i in tokenize.generate_tokens(str_io.readline):
    arr.append(i[1])
    if i[1] == '.':
      last_delim = cnt
    cnt = cnt + 1

  # Join the namespace parts into a string
  ns = ""
  for i in range(0,last_delim):
    ns = ns + arr[i]

  # Join the attr parts into a string
  attr = ""
  for i in range(last_delim + 1, len(arr)):
    attr = attr + arr[i]

  return (ns, attr)
```

This should work with intermediate index/keys as well. (i.e "mod.ns[3].obj.dict['key']")

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the namespace is always alphanumeric, you could first split on `/[^a-zA-Z.]/`, then `rsplit` on `.`:

```
>>> import re
>>> ns_attr_split = lambda s: re.split("[^a-zA-Z.]", s, 1)[0].rsplit('.')
>>> ns_attr_split("obj.dict['key.word']") 
['obj', 'dict']
```

Obviously this isn't *exactly* what you want… but the fiddling would be straight forward.

Comment: Hmm... I'll have to play with this, but nice option.

Comment: Yep. Beyond that, you'd have to either get a bit more specific, or write a real parser (or possibly use `ast.parse`). For example, would `foo.bar[baz[bam[fish]]()['cat']].egg` be allowed?

Answer (score 0):

A fun little regular expression problem...

This code works on all the examples you provided using Python 2.6, and assumes you don't have any intermediate index/key accesses (e.g. "obj['foo'].baz"):

```
import re
ns_attr_split = lambda s: re.match(r"((?:\w+\.)*\w+)\.(.+)", s).groups()
```